# Immigration clearance in Canada

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, canada, connecting-flights

We are flying from O'Hare to Edmonton via Vancouver on 30th Aug. Is there a facility of  clearing Canada immigration in Edmonton, our destination, instead of our transit airport in Vancouver?

Answer (score 6):

No. You must go through Canadian immigration in Vancouver, your first port of entry into Canada. Your Vancouver-Edmonton flight will be a regular Canadian domestic flight, and you won't be able to get to your gate until you go through immigration.